# Weakly-referenced object for TabbedPanel

Tags: python, kivy, kivy-language

I'm currently trying to implement a simple GUI using Kivy, but whenever I try to resize the GUI window, I get the "weakly-referenced object no longer exists" error. My code is attached below.

.py file:

```
import kivy
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.uix.floatlayout import FloatLayout
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.tabbedpanel import TabbedPanel
from kivy.properties import ObjectProperty, StringProperty


class GUI(TabbedPanel):
    pass



class GUIApp(App):
    def build(self):
        return GUI()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    GUIApp().run()
```

.kv file:

```
<GUI>:
  
  
    do_default_tab: False
    
    TabbedPanelItem:
        text: 'Split'
        GridLayout:
            rows: 2
            cols: 2
            padding: [10, 10]
            spacing: [10, 10]
            row_default_height: 10
            Button:
                text: 'test1'
            Button:
                text: 'test2'
            Button:
                text: 'test3'
            Button:
                text: 'test4'
    TabbedPanelItem:
        text: 'Fit'
        Label:
            text: 'TestFit'
```

I tried adding

```
Id: Id.__self__
```

in the .kv file to create a strong reference, however, this did not seem to work.

Addendum: I tried on a different machine, where the problem does not occur. The error I get is:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
   File "C:\Users\dgra\Desktop\kLa Code\Test\main.py", line 19, in <module>
     GUIApp().run()
   File "C:\Users\dgra\.conda\envs\Kiwi\lib\site-packages\kivy\app.py", line 855, in run
     runTouchApp()
   File "C:\Users\dgra\.conda\envs\Kiwi\lib\site-packages\kivy\base.py", line 504, in runTouchApp
     EventLoop.window.mainloop()
   File "C:\Users\dgra\.conda\envs\Kiwi\lib\site-packages\kivy\core\window\window_sdl2.py", line 747, in mainloop
     self._mainloop()
   File "C:\Users\dgra\.conda\envs\Kiwi\lib\site-packages\kivy\core\window\window_sdl2.py", line 479, in _mainloop
     EventLoop.idle()
   File "C:\Users\dgra\.conda\envs\Kiwi\lib\site-packages\kivy\base.py", line 339, in idle
     Clock.tick()
   File "C:\Users\dgra\.conda\envs\Kiwi\lib\site-packages\kivy\clock.py", line 591, in tick
     self._process_events()
   File "kivy\_clock.pyx", line 384, in kivy._clock.CyClockBase._process_events
   File "kivy\_clock.pyx", line 414, in kivy._clock.CyClockBase._process_events
   File "kivy\_clock.pyx", line 412, in kivy._clock.CyClockBase._process_events
   File "kivy\_clock.pyx", line 154, in kivy._clock.ClockEvent.tick
   File "kivy\_clock.pyx", line 86, in kivy._clock.ClockEvent.get_callback
   File "C:\Users\dgra\.conda\envs\Kiwi\lib\site-packages\kivy\weakmethod.py", line 56, in is_dead
     return self.proxy is not None and not bool(dir(self.proxy))
 ReferenceError: weakly-referenced object no longer exists
```

Comment: I cannot reproduce your problem. Does your posted code demonstrate the issue? Please post the full stacktrace of the error message.